# Is it possible to populate a generic list and return it from a method in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method that uses reflection to populate an array of `Object[]`, the method currently returns Object[] and I would like to cast it to the actual reflected class instance that was created. E.g:

```
public Object[] populateReflectionObject(Class<?> c) {
    Object[] reflectionArrayPopulated = methodToCreateArrayFromReflection(c);
    return reflectionArrayPopulated;
}

FinalObject[] populate = (Object[])populateReflectionObject(FinalObject.class);
```

It is not possible to cast between arrays, is it possible to achieve what I want by using generics?

Edit: I create the object that I want to cast like:

```
Object[] object = new Object[finalObjectArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < finalObjectArray.length; i++) {
   object[i] = finalObjectArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast between arrays (in this case do an unchecked downcast).

Handling it with generics (so that you can return any array type) would be something like this

```
public <T> T[] populateReflectionObject(Class<T> c) {
    Object reflectionArrayPopulated = ...
    return (T[]) reflectionArrayPopulated;
}
```

Edit: The snippet below is more accurate (if I got what you are trying to do right this time).

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T[] createArray(Class<T> clazz, int length) {
    return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, length);
}
```

Comment: I get a ClassCastException when I cast from (T[])object

Comment: How do you create the array given the class? Are you sure it is an array populated with instances of this class?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to generify your method and suppress warnings about casting arrays:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestClass {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T[] createArray(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = createArray(String.class);
        strings[0] = "Hello";
        strings[1] = "World";
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));
    }
}
```

I'm using a static method here, but it works on instance methods as well. Note that the call in the main method does not need casting.

Comment: Note that `Array.newInstance(klazz, 3, 4, 5)` (with `int...` parameter) would `new T[3][4][5]` so this very generalizing method can only return `Object`. Hence the need for a cast at the call.

Comment: @JoopEggen: the reason I did the `Array.newInstance` call was that it was the first thing that came to mind for setting up a SSCCE (as opposed to calling a non-existent `methodToCreateArrayFromReflection(c)`). I guess it might be a bit confusing in this context.

Comment: My remark was not meant as criticism, it is a fine answer with for many novices a new player, Array. Just wanted to explain the need for a cast, and show its multidimensional capabilities.